# Why is my Angularjs Service not allowing me to call it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make an Angular Service that houses common functions. 
I bundled the code within my MVC app:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Angular")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/app", "*.js", true));
```

And I checked in Developer Tools if it actually brought in my Common Folder with Common.js :

[image: Common.js Is second in the list]

I added Common to the App :

```
var app = angular.module('app',
[
    'JobCtrl',
    'JobSvc',
    'WebsiteCtrl',
    'WebsiteSvc',
    'myClientCtrl',
    'ClientSvc',
    'MediaCompanyCtrl',
    'MediaCompanySvc',
    'PageAlertSvc',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.bootstrap.tpls',
    'Common'
]
```

);

and to the Controller:

```
    angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls'])
.controller('JobCtrl',
        [
            'JobService',
            'WebsiteService',
            'MediaCompanyService',
            'ProductService',
            '$scope',
            '$uibModal',
            'PageAlertService',
            'Common',
            function (JobService, WebsiteService, MediaCompanyService,
                ProductService, $scope, $uibModal,PageAlertService, Common)
```

This is what my Common.js file looks like:

```
    angular.module('app')
.service('Common', function () {

    this.heyThere = function ()
    {
        console.log('Just wanted to say hey there')
    };

});
```

Whenever it is called within my JobCtrl I get a `Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider`.

Could anyone see what I may be doing wrong where it won't recognize my Common.js file? When I move Common.js to the Services folder and try calling it within my controller it works, but not when it is in my Common Folder. Makes no sense!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be careful when you use the **declaration** of a module. You are basically reassigning the `app` module to different instances.

```
angular.module('app', [dependencies]) //Constructs a module with dependencies
angular.module('app').service(...) //Associates the components (service)
                                   //with the app module.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am still getting the same error even with this change! @Muli Yulzary

Comment: Check for other files with the same `angular.module('app', [dependencies])` pattern. Your controller file and app file.

Comment: The only other places I have dependencies where I call my app module is in my Controller. Could those be causing my issue?

Comment: You need to specify the dependencies **once** in only **one** file as I've already mentioned.

Comment: When i remove the dependency from my Controller it bombs the application give me a `Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error`. I still have the dependency in the app.js as I have it above.

Comment: Good. That's a different error. It basically means one of the dependencies can't be resolved.

Comment: Alright. I may have to ask another question since I am not sure of how to solve this issue now. I will accept your answer and possibly start a new one. Thank you! @Muli Yulzary

Answer (score 2):

That is simply because you are defining your app..twice!!!!

```
angular.module('app', []) // this is where you re-define your app
.service('Common', function () {

    this.heyThere = function ()
    {
        console.log('Just wanted to say hey there')
    };

});
```

should be:

```
angular.module('app')
.service('Common', function () {

    this.heyThere = function ()
    {
        console.log('Just wanted to say hey there')
    };

});
```

the module function has 2 modes.. with 2 arguments you are setting up your app.. with a single argument you just getting a reference to an existing app (which is already defined before that)

Comment: Although your answer should be right, I changed my Service to reflect what you have stated ( which sadly I should be more careful of how I call my angular app) and it's still giving me the same error!

Comment: first - you can always up vote any answer you like :) and second - are you sure that this is the ONLY place you use such a technic?

Comment: Do you mean a "technic" like another js technology? And yes, the only places I call it currently are in the app.js and my controller. As soon as I pull it out of my controller the controller no longer is recognized.